# Python process http link header without regex

Tags: python, http-headers

Some HTTP responses can have a link header such as `<http://www.i_am_a_url.com>;rel="meta data"`.

Does anyone know any clean ways to grab the url? I'd rather not use regex if possible as regex makes for a horrible read in code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [lxml](http://lxml.de/)

```
impoprt lxml.html

root = lxml.html.fromstring(response_content_string)
for a in root.cssselect('a[href]'):
    print(a)
```

OR

```
impoprt lxml.html

root = lxml.html.fromstring(response_content_string)
for el, attr, url, _ in root.iterlinks():
    print(url)
```